# Getting TextBox values from another class

Tags: c#, winforms

Got still no solution after over 5 hours of searching and trying...
I've got 2 classes (lets call them Form1 and Form2). Form 1 has  two TextBoxes with values and a button. When I trigger this button, Form2 shall be opened and calculate something with the values which are written in the TextBoxes of Form1.

Here is my code (if you need it):

Form1:

```
namespace Darlehensrechner
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for Annuitätendarlehen.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class Annuitätendarlehen : Window
{

    public Annuitätendarlehen()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void berechnen2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        double zins = 0.03;
        double ZwErg1 = 0;
        double ZwErg2 = 0;
        double ZwErg3 = 0;
        double gSumme = 0;

        int monate;
        monate = Convert.ToInt32(monate2.Text);
        monate = int.Parse(monate2.Text);

        int betrag;
        betrag = Convert.ToInt32(betrag2);
        betrag = int.Parse(betrag2.Text);

        Annuitätenrechner annuitätenrechner = new Annuitätenrechner();
        //AnRe.AnRechner();
    }
}
}
```

Form2:

```
namespace Darlehensrechner
{
class Annuitätenrechner : Annuitätendarlehen
{
     Annuitätendarlehen annuitätendarlehen = new Annuitätendarlehen();

    public void AnRechner(int monate, int betrag)
    {
        double zins = 0.03;
        double ZwErg1 = 0;
        double ZwErg2 = 0;
        double ZwErg3 = 0;
        double gSumme = 0;


        ZwErg1 = Math.Pow((1 + zins), monate * zins); //(1 + zins)^monate * zins / (1 + zins) ^ monate - 1;
        ZwErg2 = Math.Pow((1 + zins), monate - 1);
        ZwErg3 = ZwErg1 / ZwErg2;
        gSumme = ZwErg3 * betrag;

        rechnung2.Text = ZwErg1 + "   = Part 1: (1 + zins^monate * zins)" + Environment.NewLine +
            ZwErg2 + "   = Part 2: (1 + zins) ^ monate - 1" + Environment.NewLine +
            ZwErg3 + "   = Part 1 - Part 2";

        summeAn.Content = gSumme.ToString("0.00");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You have to invoke the method AnRechner with the values: annuitätenrechner.AnRechner(monate, betrag)

Comment: Why do you need to wrap an instance of base class in the subclass?  "Annuitätendarlehen annuitätendarlehen = new Annuitätendarlehen()"

Comment: @Jesus wrote it some time ago just to try something out. The calculation works now :) That new Annuitätendarlehen line is useless right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, where is the problem?

```
//int monate; 
int monate = Convert.ToInt32(monate2.Text);
//monate = int.Parse(monate2.Text); //you do not need this because the code above do the same

//int betrag;
int betrag = Convert.ToInt32(betrag2.Text);
//betrag = int.Parse(betrag2.Text); //you do not need this because the code above do the same

Annuitätenrechner annuitätenrechner = new Annuitätenrechner();
// after creating instance just to call method and pass parameters
annuitätenrechner.AnRechner(monate, betrag);
```

It is a bad desing of using methods of derived class in the base class.
You do not need this line

```
Annuitätendarlehen annuitätendarlehen = new Annuitätendarlehen();
```

in the `Annuitätenrechner` class

Comment: It doesn't show anymore errors now, thanks. But it still doesn't show the result of the calculation, have you any idea why it is like that? Sorry my dumb questions, I'm new to this coding language.

Comment: @SebDammer Of course the result won't show because you did not describe where you want to display the result. and what is the `summeAn`??

Comment: summeAn is a label placed in the Annuitätendarlehen class (Form1). that is the label where gSumme should be shown

Answer (score 0):

in form1 create two static variables :

```
public static int Value1;
public static int value2;
```

on button click:

```
 value1=convert.toint32(textbox1.Text);
 value2=convert.toint32(textbox2.Text);
```

and to show form2

```
Form2 obj = new Form2();
obj.show();
```

and in form 2 load event calculate your values.

```
int Sum=Form1.Value1+Form1.value2
```

`MessageBox.Show(Sum.ToString());`